# Death of a Black Hole ≠ Rebirth?

Tags: black-hole, hawking-radiation

So we all know that Stephen Hawking proved that Black Holes do evaporate overtime through hawking radiation. But that energy is released in very discrete amounts and there will be a time in the universe when there would not be any stars left and we would only have black holes. And here is where my question comes in: After we see the blackhole era of the universe won't we see a small blackhole that evaporates fast and all of the energy released can form stars or more?

Comment: You may enjoy exploring the [Hawking radiation calculator](https://www.vttoth.com/CMS/physics-notes/311-hawking-radiation-calculator) of [Viktor Toth](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/users/7838/viktor-toth).

Comment: @Viktor Toth Thank you for the recommendation. I'll check it out right now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A star needs more than "energy" to form. It needs fuel, in the form of hydrogen.

In this distant era, there will no longer be clouds of hydrogen to collapse to form stars. So there will be no more stars.

The actual amount of energy released by a black hole is large (it is equal to the mass-energy of the black hole) But most of that energy is released very slowly at a very low power.  Only a comparatively small amount of energy is released explosively at the end of the black hole's life. Most of the energy is released as long-wavelength photons which dissipate into the universe. At the end of the black hole's life, higher energy photons and other particles will be produced, but nowhere near enough to form a star.

Comment: Thank you. This was a question that I had always wondered but go to know more about.